# Combinining several strings to a single string

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    String f = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    String s = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value.PadLeft(3,'0');
    String q = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;
    String w = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
    String o = TextBox3.Text.ToString();
```

I want to combine it to a single string i.e **String u= f+s+q+w+o**

How to do it?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you gave should work fine:

```
String u = f + s + q + w + o;
```

Note that this will be converted by the compiler into:

```
String u = String.Concat(new String[] { f, s, q, w, o });
```

EDIT: All the other answers so far have suggested that `StringBuilder` is the right way to go here. *It isn't*. `StringBuilder` is great to avoid problems like this:

```
// Bad code - don't use
string result = "";
foreach (string value in collection) {
    result += value;
}
```

In that case, there would be increasingly large temporary strings created because concatenation is performed *on each iteration of the loop*. The intermediate value is *only* required for the next iteration of the loop.

Now, in this case we know the *whole* result of the concatenation in a single go: `f + s + q + w + o`. The compiler converts that into a single invocation of `String.Concat`, so no temporary strings are required. Additionally, the `String.Concat` method can build a result string with *exactly* the right internal storage length, because it knows all of the contents to start with. In a `StringBuilder`, there's an initial capacity which is then increased through reallocation where necessary. That means that usually *either* the resulting string has a larger backing store than it needs, *or* there's a final "copy" stage to convert to a string of the right size. (Which course of action is taken is implementation-specific; I believe early versions of the framework used to do the former, and later versions do the latter.)

Answer (score 2):

```
String u= f+s+q+w+o;
```

or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(f);
sb.Append(2);
sb.Append(q);
sb.Append(w);
sb.Append(o);
```

Comment: Note that using a `StringBuilder` here will probably be *less* efficient than concatenation.

Comment: Only use StringBuilder() when you want to concatenate a large quantity of strings. Italy's first example is fine for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result= f+s+q+w+o; will do the trick
```

however use StringBuilder for such type of operations

EDIT **however Always use StringBuilder for such type of operations**

Comment: No, only use `StringBuilder` when it's actually the right approach.

Comment: ohh yes, i mistakenly wrote that =).. Thanks

Comment: No, you've taken my comment the wrong way. You shouldn't *always* use StringBuilder - in this case, it's less efficient! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't care about performance, **String u = f + s + q + w + o;** will actually work. The more "conventional" way of concatinating a large number of strings is by using the StringBuilder class, which you can find in the System.Text namespace:

```
public class bla
{
    public String concatSomeStrings(String a, String b, String c) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(a);
        sb.Append(b);
        sb.Append(c);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The advantage of using the string builder is that internally, it does not reallocate space for a new string for every concatination operation, so its quicker and therefore considered a more "proper" way. Personally, when all you need is to concatinate 5 strings - f+s+q+w+o is the way I prefer.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: As with all the other answers, you've missed the distinction between performing multiple concatenation operations in one go, and concatenating multiple times. StringBuilder is only preferred in the latter case.

Answer (score -1):

personally id use a stringbuild as strings are **immutable** and will thus create new objects for each use where you want an output

```
            var u = new StringBuilder();
            u.Append(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
            u.Append(DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value.PadLeft(3, '0'));
            u.Append(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
            u.Append(TextBox2.Text.ToString());
            u.Append(TextBox3.Text.ToString());
```

Comment: In this case, using `StringBuilder` will be less efficient - repeated string concatenation is a problem, but in this case all the concatenation is done in one expression, so no temporary strings are required.